# UTF-8 symbols not displaying properly in browser using Pedestal

Tags: encoding, utf-8, clojure, jetty, pedestal

I've made simplest Pedestal project and run it in my repl locally. However, after checking browser at `localhost:8890` I saw � (replacement characters) instead of actual text (cyrillic symbols) I put in my Pedestal route.

I also checked in browser devtools response headers: 
*Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8* is present.

Before you ask:

1. Yes, I set up `charset=UTF-8` in response, as you can see in code below.
2. My `core.clj` file is also in UTF-8 encoding.
3. I've tried other browsers as well, same thing.
4. *Additional info:* I'm using Windows, but have never encountered this issue before with other libraries and frameworks (*ring, yada*). Could it be that Pedestal somehow corrupts my code internally while passing it to jetty server? I dunno.

The whole code of project:

```
(ns samplepedestal.core
  (:require [io.pedestal.http :as http]
            [io.pedestal.http.route :as route])
  (:gen-class))

(defn html-response
  [req]
  {:status 200
   :body "<html lang=\"ru\">
          <head>
          <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />
          <title>Текст на русском</title>
          </head>
          <body>Текст на русском</body>
          </html>"
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html; charset=UTF-8"}})

(def routes
  (route/expand-routes
   [[["/" {:get `html-response}]]]))

(def service-map
  {::http/routes routes
   ::http/type   :jetty
   ::http/port   8890})

(defn start []
  (http/start (http/create-server service-map)))

;; -- Interactive development
(defonce server (atom nil))

(defn start-dev []
  (reset! server
          (http/start (http/create-server
                       (assoc service-map
                              ::http/join? false)))))

(defn stop-dev []
  (http/stop @server))

(defn restart []
  (stop-dev)
  (start-dev))
;; ---


(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

This is kind of strange behaviour, I have no clue what I'm missing, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you *sure* your clj file is utf-8 encoded? Try writing `\u0421` instead of `с` (or other similar substitution). If the server is sending the right headers, it seems most likely you read the wrong characters from disk. Alternatively, perhaps the font your browser is using doesn't have a glyph for those characters?

Comment: @amalloy, yes, I'm positive about utf-8 encoded clj file. I tried to write `\u0421` instead of `с` - didn't work, got same result. Fonts are fine, I pasted same html code into local html file and opened it, it showed correctly.

Comment: I ran your code on my pc and the my browser correctly displayed the cyrillic symbols.

Comment: @AlbertP, well, I'm glad for you, but the problem is still there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in how REPL starts. Have you got something along the lines of

> Starting nREPL server... "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\bin\java" **-Dfile.encoding=Cp1251**
>   -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dclojure.compile.path=D:\workspace-clojure\the-next-big-server-side-thing\target\classes
>   -Dthe-next-big-server-side-thing.version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dclojure.debug=false -Didea.launcher.port=50071 "-Didea.launcher.bin.

when REPL starts?

If so, you might want to add new JVM parameter to fix that.

[image]

Comment: I use different editor for my clojure projects - Atom with proto-repl package. I start repl either in cmd directly or in proto-repl, so I don't see any of lines you mentioned. Is there any other way to check or edit my JVM parameter rather than in IntelliJ as you show in your picture?

Comment: So yes, the problem was with my -Dfile.encoding property. Don't know, what the previous setting was for this property and how the hell did I manage to work perfectly on other Clojure projects without it, but I guess this is what you get when you jump into Clojure without dealing with Java first. Thanks for the right answer, @akond!